# I am trying to send email from round cube through my android app but it show error

Tags: android

`com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 The address is not valid`

with Gmail it was successful

Comment: Are you sure that the mail address is valid? Plus, could you please share more information with us.

Answer (score 0):

try the following steps...

- If SMTP_BLOCK is enabled but you have to allow local connections to port 25 on the server (e.g. for webmail or web scripts) then enable this option to

  ## allow outgoing SMTP connections to 127.0.0.1
- SMTP_ALLOWLOCAL = 1

If that was set to 0 before, simply change it to 1 and restart the firewall..

or Try checking the roundcube config file and ensure that the SMTP server is set to "localhost" there.